# CF 9 cflayout ajax error

Tags: coldfusion

We are upgrading from CF 8 Ent to 9 Ent - the following example runs fine on CF 8, but once in CF 9 it fails with "Error retreiving markup for selected element.. not found", the page returns a 404. Here's the interesting part - as soon as I remove the "source=" argument in cflayoutarea, the error goes away. It only happens when I specify a source.  Does anyone have any suggestion on what might be going on?  The basic stuff already set:

- "selectpage.cfm" exists and is valid and is is same directory.
- CFIDE is in a virtual directory

[image]

Comment: If you navigate straight to the page can you see it or do you get the 404 error then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, which was due to server-side config and IIS 7 security settings. In the move from IIS 6 to IIS 7 on a new server, the server admin did not correctly copy the SQL Injection exception terms from the previous config.  So, II 7 then denied certain keywords in the query string which had the only 'symptom' of a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the most current updates to ColdFusion? (9.01 Hotfix 1) I believe this may have been a know issue that was addressed by the updates.

Comment: Yes, running latest hotfix 1.  I also have a thread going at houseoffusion.com entitled "ColdFusion 9 cflayout ajax errors"